# Javascript sort multi-dimensional array - a complete example?

Tags: javascript, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm no Javascript expert and I'm having problems trying to glue together the various nuggets I find here and elsewhere regarding multi-dimensional arrays and sorting and wondered if someone could help me with a complete example?

I have managed to get to the point that I can populate a localStorage with data read in via Ajax.

The format of the rows is ...

> (msgXXX) (Key1:Value1|Key2:Value2|Key3:Value3|...etc)

where

> (msgXXX) is the localStorage key; and
>
> (Key1:Value1|Key2:Value2|Key3:Value3|...etc) is the single concatenated localStorage data string

What I want to be able to do is convert all this to a multi-dimensional array to which I can apply various sorts. For example, one of the Keys is called "Timestamp" and the value is an integer representing seconds since the Unix epoch. I would like to sort all rows based on this Timestamp value (in descending order - ie latest first). Right now the dataset is just over 600 rows.

I'm comfortable I can do the extraction and slicing and dicing to get the data out of the localStorage, but I'm not even sure what I'm aiming for with regards to populating an array and then setting up the sort.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with something like this:

```
function create(line) {
    var tokens = line.split("|");
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        tokens[i] = tokens[i].split(":");
        obj[tokens[i][0]] = tokens[i][1];
    }

    return obj;
}

var arr = [];
for (....) { // iterate over the input that each line is of key/value format
    arr.push(create(line));
}

function timestampSort(a, b) {
    if (a == b)
        return 0;

    return a.timestamp < b.timestamp ? -1 : 1;
}

// to sort by timestamp
arr.sort(timestampSort);
```

This code creates an object per key/value line, in the format you gave. The object will have the keys as attributes. All of those objects are being pushed into an array, which is then being sorted by passing a compare function to the native sort method of array.
You can of course make as many compare functions as you want, each comparing by a different attribute/criteria.

You can read more about the sort method here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

## EDIT

The *sort* method both changes the array itself and returns the array, so doing something like:

```
console.log(arr.sort(timestampSort));
```

Will both change the actual array and return it, and so the console.log will print it.
If you don't want to change the original array and have a copy of it that will get sorted you can:

```
var arr2 = arr.slice();
arr2.sort(timestampSort);
```

As for the keys in the array, what I wrote was intended to work only with this part of the line: *Key1:Value1|Key2:Value2|Key3:Value3|...etc*
So, to add support for the entire format, here's the modification:

```
function create(line) {
    var parts = line.match(/^\(msg(\d+)\) \((.+)\)$/);
    var tokens = parts[2].split("|");
    var obj = { msgID: parts[1] };
    for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        tokens[i] = tokens[i].split(":");
        obj[tokens[i][0]] = tokens[i][1];
    }
    return obj;
}
```

If you apply this to the example you gave you'll get this:

```
arr is: [{
    msgID: XXX,
    Key1: Value1,
    Key2: Value2,
    Key3: Value3
}]
```

Hope this clears things for you.

Comment: Excellent. This seems to do everything I need - except I don't know the right syntax to access the sorted array. Does arr get replaced with the sorted output or do I need to set a second array to this one? The first key in arr appears to be the line number, but how do I access other keys? Thanks. Pete.

Comment: (and others). This works: `var obj = arr[i] ; for (var j in obj) { out += j + ": " + obj[j] + "\n<br/>"; }`, but explicitly specifiying keys as `obj[Key1]` doesn't. Can you help me understand why?

Comment: When you get attributes from objects using this method you need to keep in mind that the attribute name should be a (js) primitive, that is boolean, numbers, strings, etc. With your example: *obj["Key1"]* should work. When you iterate over the attributes with the for each loop, you get the keys in their right form, in your case strings, and so: *obj[j]* works because *j* is a string.

Comment: Thanks again Nitzan. This makes perfect sense. But unfortunately it's not working. I must have made another error somewhere which is impacting my logic. Thanks.

Comment: It should work, so yeah, maybe you have something else wrong.. Also, just to make sure: it's all case-sensitive, so *obj["key"]* is different than *obj["Key"]*

Comment: Oh, and another thing, if you want to access a specific attribute you can and should use *obj.Key1*